# Get value from another model based on matching dates

Tags: python, django, filter, model

Basically, I have 2 models, Model 1 is a list of exchange rates for every day for the last 5 years. Model 2 is an invoice model.

What I would like to happen, is when the Invoice model is saved, it matches the invoice date, with the specific date in the Exchange rates table, and imports the appropriate exchange rates to the specific fields on the invoice model.

I've been trying to use something like this in the save override:

```
   invdate = obj.invoiceDate
    obj.exchange_relation=xchangeRates.objects.filter(date=invdate).values('id')
    obj.euroRate= exchangeRates.objects.filter(date=invdate).values('EuroRate')
```

Many thanks in advance! 
(Sorry there isn't more code, I think I've over confused myself with this one and have removed a lot of what I've tried!

Models as per request:

```
class exchangeRates(models.Model):
date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Exchange Rate Date')
EuroRate = models.DecimalField(verbose_name="Euro Rate", max_digits=5, decimal_places=4)
DollarRate = models.DecimalField(verbose_name="Dollar Rate", max_digits=5, decimal_places=4)

class Invoice(models.Model):
fullname = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=250, verbose_name='Invoice Name')
ctr = models.ForeignKey(CTR, related_name='CTR', verbose_name='CTR')
invoiceNo = models.CharField(max_length=6)
invoiceDate = models.DateField(null=True, verbose_name='Invoice Date')
invoiceStatus = models.ForeignKey(InvStatus, verbose_name='Status')
currency = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=3, verbose_name='Currency')
exchangeRate = models.FloatField(verbose_name='exchange rate', default=0.0)
cathieValue = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Cathie Value', default=0.0)
subcontractorValue = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Subcontractor Value', default=0.0)
expensesValue = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Expenses', default=0.0)
deductionValue = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Deduction', default=0.0)
vatInc = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='VAT Included')
netValue = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Net', default=0.0)
vatValue = models.FloatField(verbose_name='VAT', default=0.0)
GrossValue = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Gross', default=0.0)
euroRate = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Euro Rate', max_digits=5, decimal_places=4)
dollarRate = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='DollarRate', max_digits=5, decimal_places=4)
```

Comment: Please show your models.

Comment: @Gocht Added the models.. Again, there may have been some changes.

Comment: What is obj? What do you want to get, please be more clear with your question.

Comment: Sorry, I had expressed that I was new to Django/Python in the initial post, however, It wast removed.

Comment: @Gocht Basically, I want to populate the euro and dollar rate in the Invoice model with the euro and dollar rate in the exchange rates model based on matching date values

Comment: But you don't have a ForeingKey to exchangeRates, How do you want to link invoice withexchangeRates model?

Comment: @Gocht I had tried with and without. I don't want the user to have to select the exchange rate date as there are quite a lot of in a table which includes exchange rates for the last 5 year. this is why I was trying to filter based on the invoice date field

Comment: does `exchangeRates` table have multiple rows with same date? if yes then which one to use to get euroRate,  dollarRate ?

Comment: @Anush No, there is only one row per date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is based on your explanation in Question comment section:

In your save override do like:

```
try:
    exrate = exchangeRates.objects.get(date=obj.invoiceDate)
    xeuroRate = exrate.euroRate
    xdollarRate = exrate.dollarRate 
except:
    xeuroRate = 0.0 # set default value
    xdollarRate = 0.0 # set default value

obj.euroRate = xeuroRate
obj.dollarRate = xdollarRate
obj.save()
```

Comment: Anush, Apologies, your previous solution worked. The issue was due to the invoice date note having a match in the Exchange Rates table. (I had only imported up to a certain date. The Revices solution obviously includes the validation to prevent the "match" error. Thank you kindly!!!